# How to assign displayName?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've registered an account in my Android application using Firebase and there are multiple textfields.

How can I assign particular textfield as displayName of user so that I can later access it using `getDisplayName()`?

Answer (score 0):

To change a user's display name, you need to [update the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile):

> ```
> FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
>
> UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
>         .setDisplayName("Jane Q. User")
>         .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
>         .build();
>
> user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
>         .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
>                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>                     Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated.");
>                 }
>             }
>         });
> ```

Comment: I saw this answer earlier. But I was hoping for another solution. I wanted to know how displayName is set as default. Using firebaseuser and firebaseauth I have found uid and email of users but when I use getDisplayName I only get null value. So there's no other way to set displayname it seems.

Comment: The initial value of the display name property depends on the sign-in method. For email+password, there is no initial value, and it can only be set by calling `updateProfile`. For social providers there *may* be an initial value, which can then be changed through `updateProfile`.